# C# objectlistview undefined offset in cell editor

Tags: c#, textbox, components, objectlistview, treelistview

I use `TreeListView` component from `ObjectListView` library. I make cell values editable and when i double click on them `TextBox` will appear with odd offset.
I want to remove this offset, but how?

before start editing
[image]

after start editing
[image]

As you can see first row, second column ("My new device"), `TextBox` is appeared with offset.

P.S. Editing work as expected. Only offset is annoying me

P.P.S. As you can see the offset depends of first column offset. How i can change it to zero?
[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

After long searches i found solution!

**Source code of OLV, ObjectListView.cs**

```
public virtual void StartCellEdit(OLVListItem item, int subItemIndex) {
            OLVColumn column = this.GetColumn(subItemIndex);
            Control c = this.GetCellEditor(item, subItemIndex);
            Rectangle cellBounds = this.CalculateCellBounds(item, subItemIndex);
            c.Bounds = this.CalculateCellEditorBounds(item, subItemIndex, c.PreferredSize);

            // Try to align the control as the column is aligned. Not all controls support this property
            Munger.PutProperty(c, "TextAlign", column.TextAlign);

            // Give the control the value from the model
            this.SetControlValue(c, column.GetValue(item.RowObject), column.GetStringValue(item.RowObject));

            // Give the outside world the chance to munge with the process
            this.CellEditEventArgs = new CellEditEventArgs(column, c, cellBounds, item, subItemIndex);
            this.OnCellEditStarting(this.CellEditEventArgs);
            if (this.CellEditEventArgs.Cancel)
                return;

            // The event handler may have completely changed the control, so we need to remember it
            this.cellEditor = this.CellEditEventArgs.Control;

            this.Invalidate();
            this.Controls.Add(this.cellEditor);
            this.ConfigureControl();
            this.PauseAnimations(true);
        }
```

I saw `CellEditEventArgs` contains `Control`, that drawed in area named `Bounds`.

This function in the source file append offset to control's bounds:

```
protected Rectangle CalculateCellEditorBoundsStandard(OLVListItem item, int subItemIndex, Rectangle cellBounds, Size preferredSize) {
            if (this.View == View.Tile)
                return cellBounds;

            // Center the editor vertically
            if (cellBounds.Height != preferredSize.Height)
                cellBounds.Y += (cellBounds.Height - preferredSize.Height) / 2;

            // Only Details view needs more processing
            if (this.View != View.Details) 
                return cellBounds;

            // Allow for image (if there is one). 
            int offset = 0;
            object imageSelector = null;
            if (subItemIndex == 0)
                imageSelector = item.ImageSelector;
            else {
                // We only check for subitem images if we are owner drawn or showing subitem images
                if (this.OwnerDraw || this.ShowImagesOnSubItems)
                    imageSelector = item.GetSubItem(subItemIndex).ImageSelector;
            }
            if (this.GetActualImageIndex(imageSelector) != -1) {
                offset += this.SmallImageSize.Width + 2;
            }

            // Allow for checkbox
            if (this.CheckBoxes && this.StateImageList != null && subItemIndex == 0) {
                offset += this.StateImageList.ImageSize.Width + 2;
            }

            // Allow for indent (first column only)
            if (subItemIndex == 0 && item.IndentCount > 0) {
                offset += (this.SmallImageSize.Width * item.IndentCount);
            }

            // Do the adjustment
            if (offset > 0) {
                cellBounds.X += offset;
                cellBounds.Width -= offset;
            }

            return cellBounds;
        }
```

We can see, that offset appending to every cell (not only first). Also we can se, that `CellEditEventArgs` contains `CellBounds`.

So we can just reset `Control.Bounds` to `CellBounds` value:

```
//...
dataTreeView.CellEditStarting += DisableInputValueForCollections;
//...
        private static void DisableInputValueForCollections(object sender, CellEditEventArgs e)
        {
            RemoveExtraOffsetForNotFirstColumnInputControl(e);
            var node = e.RowObject as DataTreeNode;

            if (node != null && e.Column.AspectName == "Value")
            {
                if (node.IsContainer()) e.Cancel = true;
            }
        }
//...
private static void RemoveExtraOffsetForNotFirstColumnInputControl(CellEditEventArgs e)
        {
            if (e.Column.AspectName != "Name")
            {
                e.Control.Bounds = e.CellBounds;
            }
        }
//...
```

Comment: Thank for help. Strange behaviour of objectList. This is bug of feature?

Comment: I think, its bug. But better ask the developers

Answer (score 1):

The issue still exists in OLV v2.9.1. I worked around it slightly different than *muzagursiy* did.

```
        olv.CellEditStarting += (sender, args) =>
        {
            // Left align the edit control
            args.Control.Location = args.CellBounds.Location;

            // Readjust the size of the control to fill the whole cell if CellEditUseWholeCellEffective is enabled
            if (args.Column.CellEditUseWholeCellEffective)
            {
                args.Control.Size = args.CellBounds.Size;
            }

        };
```